# Ambiguous column name for associated Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I get an error anytime I query the DB with

```
hotels = Hotel.joins(:area).where("title LIKE ? OR address LIKE ? OR area.title LIKE ?", "%#{keywords}%", "%#{keywords}%", "%#{keywords}%") if keywords.present?
```

the error I get is

> SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: title: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "hotels" INNER JOIN "areas" ON "areas"."id" = "hotels"."area_id" WHERE (title LIKE '%a%' OR address LIKE '%a%' OR area.title LIKE '%a%')

I have read other articles but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 2):

You must specify from which table you want to look for, as you're doing in your last `LIKE` statement, where you're specifying the `title` column from the `area` table

```
OR area.title LIKE ?
```

Maybe you have in both tables which you're using in your query a column called `title` and this way SQLite doesn't know in which table to look and run the query.

You're already using the `area.title` but not the `hotel.title` so maybe there's the problem, try making the query in that way.

```
Hotel.joins(:area).where('hotel.title LIKE ? OR address LIKE ? OR area.title LIKE ?', "%#{keywords}%", "%#{keywords}%", "%#{keywords}%") if keywords.present?

=> SELECT "hotels".* FROM "hotels" INNER JOIN "areas" ON "areas"."id" = "hotels"."area_id" WHERE (hotel.title LIKE '%area-title-0%' OR address LIKE '%area-title-0%' OR area.title LIKE '%area-title-0%')
=> #<Hotel::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x3fcd4355198c>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it work by changing the column name of the Hotel.title to the Hotel.name and joins(:area) (singular) as it is a belongs to Association then using areas.title(plural) as it's a table name

```
hotels = Hotel.joins(:area).where("name LIKE ? OR address LIKE ? OR areas.title LIKE ?", "%#{keywords}%", "%#{keywords}%", "%#{keywords}%") if keywords.present?
```

Comment: While this does work, it promotes a bad choice. You shouldn't have to change the column name to make this work instead you should select the table AND the column as suggested by @sebastián-palma suggested. 

`Hotel.joins(:area).where('hotel.title LIKE ? OR address LIKE ? OR area.title LIKE ?', "%#{keywords}%", "%#{keywords}%", "%#{keywords}%") if keywords.present?`

Where `"hotel.title"` represents `"table.column"`